# Pyinstaller unpacking missing cookie

Tags: python, pyinstaller, reverse-engineering

I am trying to unpack compiled pyinstaller exe using pyinstxtractor but I am facing an issue :

```
PS C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\xxxx> python .\pyinstxtractor.py '.\xxxx.exe'
[+] Processing .\xxxx.exe
[!] Error : Missing cookie, unsupported pyinstaller version or not a pyinstaller archive
```

File type is an EXE

```
xxxx.exe: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows
```

I have tried to fix the magic number but nothing.

Comment: Did you know what is the pyinstaller version that the file was compiled?

Comment: No, and I don't think that I could.